# How to add a custom tracking field in Alfresco Activiti Workflow

Tags: model, workflow, task, alfresco, activiti

My aim is to add a custom field in a workflow which tracks the inputs during the workflow steps as the bpm:comment property.

So i tried to add a simple custom property field in bpm-model:

```
<type name="bpm:task">
         <parent>cm:content</parent>
            <properties>
            <property name="bpm:test_field">
                    <type>d:text</type>
                </property>
 ...
```

Then i added a "field filter control" in the Alfresco WorkDesk bootstrap.xml  and the flow basic step control shows my new field.

Unfortunately the field won't show the history input.

The task inherits every time the field but won't historize anything.

I didn't understand why...can anybody help me?

thanks!

Comment: you mean to say the value assigned during previous task is not visible in next task. Is it the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using process *execution* scoped variable to store the *task* scoped variable value after finishing the task, and do conversely at the beginning of the next task (writing data from execution variable to task variable). That should give you effect you expect.

Comment: i tried to copy bpm:comment to my custom task without any result...really don't know at this point...

Comment: what do you mean you 'copied bpm:comment to your custom task'? i don't understand i'm afraid..

Comment: sorry, i mean, in my flow (which is a mere copy of activiti adhoc task) i tried to add:
execution.setVariable('bpm_test_field', task.getVariable('bpm_comment').toString());
I put this exactly under the WorkflowDueDate statement (which should make the same job but doesn't work either)...

Comment: ok but did you do reversed operation on entering the next task? sth like task.setVariable('bpm_comment', execution.getVariable('bpm_test_field')); ?

Comment: it worked!! i thought the field would inheritance would work in another way, but now it's clear.
It's a bit weird...i have to create 2 fields for every inputable data..

Answer (score 0):

See there are two type of properties workflow properties and task properties.Scope of workflow properties are through out workflow and scope of task variable is limited to task only.We can copy the value from one to another as follow.

```
   <task name="yourtask" swimlane="assignee">
          <event type="task-create">
             <script>
                if (bpm_workflowDueDate != void) taskInstance.dueDate = bpm_workflowDueDate;
             </script>
          </event>
      </task>
```

Task properties will be inherited in case current task is inheriting the task which has your custom property.

Comment: i tried many ways without any result (void gives me an error and i use 'undefined').

Comment: In which xml is the swimlane? I forgot to tell that i added the property in the basic bpm.model and trying to modify the bpmn now...like this:

execution.setVariable('bpm_test_field',task.getVariable('bpm_test_field').toString()); 
thanks

Comment: It is processdefinition file not model file.